# Rails devise after_sign_up_path redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

I have in my app two models for sign_in. Also i didn't generate any my controller for devise, all is build-in. My ApplicationController is such:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    case resource
      when User then request.referrer 
      when Admin::Admin then :admin_mainpage
    end
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    request.referrer
  end
```

But, when i try to sign_up new user, devise is also sign_in user, and i get `devise filter chain halted as require_no_authentication rendered or redirected`

But how to do, that if i just sign_in in system i'm redirected to previous page, but when i'm registering new user i sign_in but redirect to root_path?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it a good solution, but try something like:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    case resource
      when User then 
        if request.referrer.to_s.include? "sign_up"
          root_path
        else
          request.referrer 
        end
      when Admin::Admin then :admin_mainpage
    end
  end
```